# wp_is_post_autosave is not working

Tags: facebook, wordpress, autosave

I want to auto publish all articles of my WP blog on Facebook without using any plugin.

I wrote some working code to do that and it's OK... but I also need to invoke this code only when I publish a new article (not for revisions or autosave).

That's the part of my function.php file that you need to see:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'koolmind_facebook_post_article',3 );
function koolmind_facebook_post_article( $post_id ) {
    /* configuration of facebook params */
    ....
    ....
    /* end config */

    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && !wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) {

        /* retrieve some data to publish */

        /* invoke my code to publish on facebook */
    }
}
```

My code is invoked as soon as I click on "add new article", and an empty draft is sent to my Facebook page. 
In add, as soon as I insert a single char on my article body, autosave is triggered and a new post (almost empty) is sent again to facebook.

I just want to block this automatic publishing and send my data to facebook only when I press the PUBLISH button.

Is that possible?

---

UPDATE

Finally I've found the problem. There was an error inside my fb code.
Problem now is avoiding multiple pubblication when updating my post.

Here's the code now:

```
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'koolmind_facebook_post_article');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'koolmind_facebook_post_article');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'koolmind_facebook_post_article');

function koolmind_facebook_post_article( $post_id ) {
require_once 'facebook/facebook.php';

/* some code here */

//verify post is not a revision
if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $post_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $post_image = 'http://.../default.jpg'; //default image

        if( $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) ){
            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id );
            $post_image = $image_attributes[0];
        } 

        /* some code here */
    }
}
```

Let me explain the issue:

If I use these 3 hooks I have no problem, but the code is executed before my featured image is stored into the database, so $post_image is always equals to the default image.

If I use publish_post hook instead, featured image is set properly (maybe because this hook is called after all data have been saved), but I cannot avoid data sending to Facebook if I update my post (wp_is_post_revision seems not to be fired).

Hope you have a good idea... now the code is almost OK! :)

Comment: `publish_post` is indeed a [hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) that triggers when the post is **published**, so there is no time for any editing or correction. I guess the correct hook is `save_post` disabling `autosave` i.e `define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);` in your `wp-config.php`

Answer (score 1):

The 'save_post' hook '[Runs after the data is saved to the database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)'. This means you can do this validation:

```
//WP hook
//the last parameter 2 means you pass 2 variables to the callback:
//the ID and the post WP object 
add_action( 'save_post', 'koolmind_facebook_post_article',3,2 );

//Callback
function koolmind_facebook_post_article( $post_id, $post ) {

// Validation:

    //If current WP user has no permissions to edit posts: exit function
    if( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) return;

    //If is doing auto-save: exit function
    if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') AND DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    //If is doing auto-save via AJAX: exit function
    if( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) return;

    //If is a revision or an autosave version or anything else: exit function
    if( $post->post_status != 'publish') return;

    /* configuration of facebook params */

    /* invoke my code to publish on facebook */

}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'koolmind_facebook_post_article');
```

Comment: I tried with add_action('publish_post', 'koolmind_facebook_post_article'); but now nothing is published even when I click on PUBLISH :(

Comment: I see that publish_post is not a hook, so I tried with add_filter('publish_post', 'koolmind_facebook_post_article');

but it's the same...